# Why does SVN think this is a conflict?

Tags: svn, merge

My apologies in advance if this is a really obvious question - I'm new to SVN. I did my best to search for an answer but I can't find anything that addresses this specifically.

I'm getting frequent conflicts when merging branches just because of the comment block at the top of the program.

We use a comment block at the top of each program to explain what the program is, and also to keep track of changes. Each time we change a program we note our new change there. Say the live program's comment block ends like this:

```
* <developer 1> <date> <comment> *
* ******** END COMMENTS ******** *
```

Two new developers begin their own branches and add their own comment below developer 1. When developer 2 puts their code live, developer 3 merges it back into his branch. I can see that this is an obvious conflict, because they've both added a different new line.

Live:

```
* <developer 1> <date> <comment> *
* <developer 2> <date> <comment> *
* ******** END COMMENTS ******** *
```

Developer 3's branch:

```
* <developer 1> <date> <comment> *
* <developer 3> <date> <comment> *
* ******** END COMMENTS ******** *
```

So developer 3 resolves the conflict himself. The issue comes when he then tries to merge his changes into Live.

Live:

```
* <developer 1> <date> <comment> *
* <developer 2> <date> <comment> *
* ******** END COMMENTS ******** *
```

Developer 3's branch:

```
* <developer 1> <date> <comment> *
* <developer 2> <date> <comment> *
* <developer 3> <date> <comment> *
* ******** END COMMENTS ******** *
```

Surely this final scenario isn't a conflict? Developer 3's code simply has an additional line, so that must be a simple merge to do. But this repeatedly gets marked as a conflict, with this result:

```
* <developer 1> <date> <comment> *
<<<<<<< .working
* <developer 2> <date> <comment> *
* ******** END COMMENTS ******** *
=======
* <developer 2> <date> <comment> *
* <developer 3> <date> <comment> *
* ******** END COMMENTS ******** *
>>>>>>> .merge-right
```

So is this actually a correct conflict, or is SVN making a mistake?
Is there something I can do to prevent this from happening repeatedly?

Thanks!

Comment: I would assume SVN is correct and fix it.  It's not like saying "It's Subversion's fault" is going to get you anywhere.  Personally, I'd remove those comment blocks.  That's what the source code management system is for.   Have developers add descriptive check in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and to @Bathsheba).
We do use SVN commit messages with individual logins, so I agree the comment blocks at the top of the code are unnecessary. It's a holdover from before we used SVN.
I was just wondering if there was any way to prevent these conflicts arising, since they are simple but time-consuming to fix when they happen so frequently.

Comment: Yes,. remove the comments.  Stop using them.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is by design.

Do consider using SVN in the way it was *designed* to be used. Have developers commit using a login specific to them, and insist on commit messages. There's little point in embedding that into the program source.